# Dropdown is not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am sending text to Dropdown textbox from Excel file.So it should send text to dropdown textbox and will select the visible particular matched text.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="routingPanelLeft">
<p style="margin-bottom: 1em">Selecting an item will append to end of hierarchy</p>
<div id="srlSelectContainer">
<p>Select an SRL:</p>
<select id="srlSelect" class="routing-select" style="display: none;">
<option/>
<option value="11">AS-HTTS-US-CDN</option>
<option value="20">AS-HTTS-US-CORE</option>
<option value="19">AS-HTTS-US-HW</option>
<option value="15">AS-HTTS-US-LAN-SW</option>
<option value="8">AS-HTTS-US-NMS</option>
<option value="13">AS-HTTS-US-RP</option>
<option value="14">AS-HTTS-US-SEC</option>
<option value="12">AS-HTTS-US-VOICE</option>
<option value="16">AS-HTTS-US-Wireless</option>
<option value="7">AS-HTTS-WANSW</option>
<option value="22">AS-US-Unsupported-KW</option>
<option value="50">ATT-INDIA-KWL</option>
<option value="33">ATT-KWL</option>
<option value="63">BELL-IPCC-UC</option>
<option value="52">BWI-GMBH-KWL</option>
<option value="65">CISCO_IT_HTTS</option>
<option value="27">EM1-KWL</option>
<option value="29">EM2-KWL</option>
<option value="36">EMC_SOS</option>
<option value="6">HTTS</option>
<option value="55">HTTS-AMAZON</option>
<option value="57">HTTS-CNS-KWL</option>
<option value="35">HTTS-COMCAST</option>
<option value="350">HTTS-Charter</option>
<option value="25">HTTS-EUEM</option>
<option value="58">HTTS-HSBC</option>
<option value="61">HTTS-HSBC-NCMKW</option>
<option value="43">HTTS-IOX</option>
<option value="42">HTTS-IPCC</option>
<option value="47">HTTS-IPCC-VZW</option>
<option value="68">HTTS-IT</option>
<option value="269">HTTS-MICROSOFT-SP</option>
<option value="60">HTTS-MSGNS</option>
<option value="56">HTTS-Mobility</option>
<option value="24">HTTS-Optus</option>
<option value="54">HTTS-PlatinumPlus</option>
<option value="51">HTTS-RPLAN-RNT</option>
<option value="53">HTTS-RUSSIAN</option>
<option value="49">HTTS-SP</option>
<option value="44">HTTS-SV</option>
<option value="45">HTTS-SVTAC</option>
<option value="26">HTTS-TEST</option>
<option value="10">HTTS-UCC</option>
<option value="66">HTTS-VIDEO</option>
<option value="48">HTTS-VTACPCMM</option>
<option value="41">HTTS-WAN</option>
<option value="70">HTTS-WANSW</option>
<option value="289">HTTS-WIRELESS</option>
<option value="34">HTTS_DT</option>
<option value="369">Jabber Support</option>
<option value="290">LATAM-HTTS</option>
<option value="309">LATAM-HTTS-EMEAR</option>
<option value="2">Lan Switching</option>
<option value="59">MDS_WW-SAN</option>
<option value="3">MultiService Specialization Queues</option>
<option value="64">Nexus-Amzn-kwl</option>
<option value="30">SEG1-KWL</option>
<option value="4">Security</option>
<option value="249">TSA</option>
<option value="62">TWC-SP</option>
<option value="37">VZB_APAC</option>
<option value="38">VZB_EMEA</option>
<option value="39">WW-SOS</option>
<option value="40">WW-SOS-CIM_CR2</option>
<option value="32">WW-SOS-HTTS</option>
<option value="31">WW-SOS-TAC</option>
<option value="46">htts-nexus7k</option>
<option value="389">test_1234</option>
</select>
<span class="custom-combobox">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">45 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
<input class="custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input" title="" autocomplete="off"/>
<a class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"/>
<span class="ui-button-text"/>
</a>
</span>
</div>

<ul id="ui-id-2" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 282px; top: -227.3px; left: 268.8px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" data-type="undefined" data-id="11" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-27599" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">AS-HTTS-US-CDN</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" data-type="undefined" data-id="20" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-27600" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">AS-HTTS-US-CORE</a
</ul>
```

I have tried Select, Keys, Action class, SendKeys methods. But it is not selecting the value from the dropdown. It is sending text to the textbox , which shows results matching text options from which it should select the Value that I am sending from Excel file.

These are my efforts:

```
WebDriverWait wait11 = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
wait11.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='srlSelectContainer']/span/input"))).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='srlSelectContainer']/span/input")).sendKeys(testData);

/*WebDriverWait wait11 = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
wait11.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='srlSelectContainer']/span/input"))).sendKeys(testData);
WebDriverWait wait1= new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='srlSelectContainer']/span/input"))).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ENTER);
WebDriverWait wait2= new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='srlSelectContainer']/span/input"))).clear();
*/

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='srlSelectContainer']/span/input"))).click();*/

WebDriverWait wait2= new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='srlSelectContainer']/span/input"))).sendKeys(testData);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='srlSelectContainer']/span/input")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ENTER);
```

Please suggest me any way as it is a roadblock.

Using Chrome browser and selenium 3.40.

Comment: Can you consider updating us your exact manual steps and the code block you have tried so far along with the error stack trace you are seeing. I think you are pretty close. Thanks

Comment: Use case is : I will send text over the textbox of dropdown , so it will show matched text in dropdown, from there i need to select particular send that i am sending through Excel file.

Comment: For ex. testdata is "HTTS" - so while sending this to dropdown textbox it will show HTTS along with other values which have HTTS text in them Ex. HTTS_EUEM , from them i just want to select HTTS option.

Comment: DropDown is always a DropDown populated with options, how can you `send text over the textbox of dropdown`? Does your DropDown have a textbox?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Selenium has class for dealing with `<select>` tag dropdowns, [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("srlSelect"));
Select select = new Select(dropDown);
select.selectByVisibleText(testData);
```

Comment: Tried this same code before. it is giving ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Comment: @PayalDhameliya Are you sure? according to the code you provided you are trying to manipulate another element, an `<input>` tag under the dropdown.

Comment: i tired with id=srlSelect, but it was nt working then i tried with srlSelectContainer which is sending value to textbox .

Comment: @PayalDhameliya Can you try something? try `WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("srlSelect"));
Select select = new Select(dropDown);
select.selectByValue("30");` just to see if this is working.

Comment: Same exception.

Comment: @PayalDhameliya You can also try to wait for the `dropDown` to be visible `dropDown 
 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("srlSelect"))); Select select = new Select(dropDown);
select.selectByVisibleText(testData);`

Comment: Tried that too . Same exception.

Comment: @PayalDhameliya Can you share the link to the site?

Comment: Actually i can't as you might need My CEC login credentials and VPN access. You won't be able to access it in open network.

Comment: @PayalDhameliya with explicit wait how can it give the same exception. It should be `TimedoutException`

Comment: Yes @GaurangShah you are right. but it is giving me the same exception.

Comment: @GaurangShah WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("srlSelect"));
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("srlSelector"))).click();
  Select select = new Select(dropDown); select.selectByVisibleText(testData); . now i got TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: srlSelector (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to access hidden element as you can see there is a property named "display:none" is applied to element so to access that element you  have to change property first from none to block. Hope this will help.

```
WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('srlSelect').style.display='block'");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

Without hardcoding value(But making broswer to wait for next step !!!!)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountSelectContainer']/span/a/span[1]")).click();
        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li"));
        for (WebElement option : options) {
          if(testData.equals(option.getText()))
            option.click();
```

OR
with hardcoded value

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountSelectContainer']/span/a/span[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/a[equals(text(),'60091 - AFCENT')]")).click();
```